# How can I flatten a WPF border to make a seamless surface?

Tags: wpf, xaml, border

I have rectangles that have different colored borders to represent different statuses. I'm trying to create a placeholder shape that is just the background color. To make them all uniform sizes, I'm adding a border that is the same color as the default background for this placeholder. You can see it in the image below. However, there's a small inner line, or edge, on the border that I can't get rid of, which prevents it from looking like a "flat" surface. How can I remove that line? The border currently is:

```
<Border Margin="2.5" BorderBrush="{Binding exampletext, FallbackValue=#00bc00}"
            Background="#788585" BorderThickness="4"
            CornerRadius="3">
```

[image: Placeholder object]

Answer (score 0):

Do not set BorderThichkness and probably BorderBrush is also not needed:

```
<Border Margin="2.5" 
        Background="#788585" 
        CornerRadius="3">
```

**Update**: if you need that 4 pixel wide placeholder, you can try with Padding maybe:

```
<Border Margin="2.5" 
        Background="#00bc00" Padding="4"
        CornerRadius="3">
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear - normally these rectangles have colored borders that denote different statuses. So to keep this "placeholder" version the same size as all the others, it needs to have a border with the same thickness.